# Anyone able to ID and provide information about this mountain bike? (DK, Club Roost, FSA)

Tags: mountain-bike

I've had this bike for several years but I don't know anything about it. It would be interesting to find out the exact model and see what comes up on the internet about it. Everything is exactly how it was when I came into possession of the bike, with the exception of the gear-shifter and saddle that were both replaced. I also added a basic speedometer and bell.

On the front it has the DK logo and it also says Club Roost on the handlebars. The headset thing says FSA Orbit and the top-cap above is an FSA Conix. On the side of the frame is has a letter that looks like a backwards Z. I believe the wheel size is 26". There are 8 gears in total. Would anyone happen to know specifically what bike this is, and what modifications has it had? I assume the pedals are different to the ones that were included initially.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a custom bike.

It’s a Saracen team M.A.D frame from late 90’s early 00’s 
with as you correctly say dk stem and club roost bars
The Rear Mech looks like Shimano Deore.
The Forks: RST - most likely, Cranks - Gusset pigmy perhaps? And Pedals are Tioga
Shimano Stx RC brake levers
And that looks like a Mavic D521 rim on the rear.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I wanted to know! I did suspect it was custom-made like you said because there were parts from all different manufacturers. It's really interesting to find out so much information. I actually came about the bike after someone fly-tipped it outside my house several years ago in a mound of rubbish. I replaced the chain and gear selector which were both broken, but everything else has been fine. Would the bike hold much value once tidied? I'm not sure how it rates but it feels quite weighty and well-produced.

Comment: @OnePlus no problem, good for a freebie! And in it’s day it was a fairly decent spec, certainly made me feel nostalgic! Although it is showing it’s age. If you are doing it it up there are a few ways you could go. Appeal to retro mtb crowd e.g. https://www.moredirt.com/ratemyride/bike/9329  or go for a more youthful dirt jump crowd e.g https://www.moredirt.com/ratemyride/bike/21263 I wouldn’t invest too much money on parts Hunt for 2nd hand bits online, value wise it’s not going to be loads. a smart retro Saracen xile is on eBay now at £129

Comment: Good to know it was a relatively decent bike back when it was still modern. I've had a lot of enjoyment out of it and it's probably made me a bit healthier at the same time! Although I did fall off it once when my shoelace got wrapped around the pedal, lol. I do like the example in the second link you posted, it looks a lot better than the colour scheme it has currently. With a good clean and new coat of paint, it should hopefully appear a bit more presentable!